# URL is unknown to Google - Will this still be indexed?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, html, search-engine-indexing

I am cloaking my website over a site I have developed in replit, but found a way to cloak over a pre-existing domain through managing DNS records and choosing a "cloak" method. This is a simple way to benefit easily from the domain without paying any extra cost, other than buying the domain name itself, which is what I have used.

I know a substantial amount of SEO and ranking, but never have used it. I am trying to get my page indexed by google, this displays this page after testing for a URL inspection.

Could this be a potential block due to "cloaking" as it could be used maliciously or is there any other way to do this in a similar way? Or use of CNAME to display over a domain?

The page is also very simple, mobile friendly design and does not have any other pages that may need to be crawled which is why something must be going on as it would have already been indexed for a page like this within 24 hours or less even.
[image]

However, on the status page of my website, it includes:
URL is unknown to Google and doesn't provide much else information on about it.
[image]

Does this information seem normal to be "Not Applicable" as it just wasn't indexed? then why would it say "indexing allowed? N/A" when it also displays it can be reached by google and "could" be indexed and selected as canonical.
[image]

I have done research about this issue, but most of them are old and outdated which doesn't help or provide extended detail about the issue.
I just find it gets confusing as it says "URL is available to google" and it could be selected and scanned as canonical, on the other hand, some research shows that it won't be indexed but never provides any other information about the issue.

The page is a portfolio site, which I am first practicing SEO on with all the the knowledge I have read from the guides that google has fully provided. But I need it to be indexed as a goal that I can use for further websites or highly informational websites I use or create in the future. Hope anyone here has knowledge about Search engine optimization, as the google support is always slow and I have tried to search for other communities but none were available.

Hopefully someone can give some reason or a detailed explanation of what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: What does "cloaking" mean to you. You do not appear to be using it in its usual meaning. (Cloaking is not typically done at the DNS level). Also, is your intent to show Search Engines different content to visitors?

Comment: Through the domain manager, there is an option to select different methods and that is shown under manage DNS > fowarding then setting the method to "cloak". Other option are: ,301 Permanent, 302 Temporary and HTML redirect Actually, what is the HTML redirect? But I am using the cloak option to display over my domain name a website I created through code elsewhere

Comment: Who is your registrar?  I suggest to you that whatever you are doing with "cloaking" is dodgy, and you likely don't yet know how much you don't know about SEO.   The appropriate methods to permanently transfer from 1 URL to another is to use a 301 redirect.  An HTML  redirect is HTML on a page, typically with code like <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.example.com'" />

Comment: The words "display over my domain name a website " is a meaningless statement as there is no way to display a domain name over a website - a domain name is used to resolve a websites location.  I  suspect you actually mean you are using a reverse proxy or iframe - but unless you can articulate the technology used we cant meaningfully help you as you have not described the operational mechanism being used.

Comment: yes it uses Iframe and displays the whole resolution over the page but then the site (vip.ventraip.com.au) calls that cloaking

Comment: https://ventraip.com.au/faq/article/adding-domain-redirects-using-vipcontrol/ almost implies that you are not using an iframe (because it talks about a mirror image).  If you are indeed using an iframe you can't do SEO on the parent domain name and expect it to work on another site, as the iframe is a "browser trick" - and from a search engines perspective the domain name is still the target domain name.  IFRAMES are a bad tool to use for SEO.

Comment: so best answer is to buy a host file manager to directly display html over the domain itself?

Comment: then why does it say when I test live url, it says everything is available and mobile friendly, then also says "it could possibly be selected as canonical"

Comment: I've had a quick chat with VentraIP and you are right.  its an iFrame.   Run a mile from this technology.

Comment: so what do you recommend?

Comment: "what do you recommend?" - as @davidgo said, " Run a mile from this technology"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have established that a "Cloak" is a vendor specific term for an iFrame and its description on that site is misleading in many respects  (this is not controvertial - the helpdesk person agreed with me with my suggested edit to their description).

You will have a great deal of difficulty getting any meaningful SEO traction with an IFRAME, as from a search engines POV there is no content in the site associated with the domain name.

In order to have your new domain name show the content for your old URL you would need to either make the website answer for the old and new domain name and display the content, or set up the new domain name to transparently proxy requests to the old website (you might be able to use something like Cloudflare for this?) or set up a second copy.   It is somewhat unlikely you will find a high quality way to do this for free on cheap hosting.

I would recommend steering clear of CNAMES.  They are a trap for people who don't understand DNS.  If you control the domain names it is usually better to use an A record.   A CNAME/A Record solution will only point the DNS to an appropriate server.  The webserver needs to associate the domain name with the website.

Speaking generically, the best way to transfer the "Google Juice" is to set up 301 redirects from the new domain to the existing site.  It will mean the new site does not get any Google love long term, but it may add to the google juice of the target site.

I'm not sure how much you know about IFRAMES - so I'll explain it simply here.  An iFrame is simply a command to a web browser to embed another page in the existing page.   It has some limited uses (eg displaying a youtube video on your site or a google map).   The HTML used would boil down to something like:

```
  <iframe src="https://www.example.com" title="Description Here"></iframe>
```

Note that the above is what Google sees when trying to index the site with the iframe.   There is no content or keywords there. There is nothing to assist Google in working out the reason for the connection between the sites, nor to classify the parent site.  Google would have no compelling reason to assume information in the iframe src is meaningful in the context of a parent domain.

Comment: Are you certain googlebot doesn't interpret the link and include the content?  Citation needed.

Comment: @Steve I fear you misunderstand me.  I'm not saying Goolebot does not interpret the link - indeed it likely does.  I'm saying it does not associate the content of the link with the parent site.

Comment: Google does index content if an iframe as part of the containing page, but it has limitations. e.g. most meta tags are removed. Use GSC to inspect the outer page and view the html generated. iframing a whole site has other issues. No matter where the user navigates, the address bar will still be for the home page. Links in the iframe will probably not go back to the outer domain, causing crawling and indexing issues.

Comment: This whole thread threw me for a loop. @davidgo you're a gentleman and a scholar.